# Dreamweaver PHP and Contact PHP is not Working

Tags: php, html

My contact form is not sending to email. I have saved my contact page to "contact.php" with my PHP file being "contact_us.php". Please help.

The HTML code in "contact.php":

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
      <div id="contact_body">

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Name</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
         <h4>Phone Number</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone Number" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>E-mail</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
         <h4>Date of Event</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date of Event" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"> </p>
        </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <h4>Location of Event</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Location of Event" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"> </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Service You Are Interested In</h4>
          <p class="text_cont"><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Service" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h4>Number of Children Attending </h4>
          <p class="text_cont"> <input type="number" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Number Attending" class="input-cont-textarea"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4>Additional Information </h4>
          <p class="text_cont" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Additional Information" required="true" class="input-cont-textarea" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><div id="contact_results"></div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12"><p><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-default" value="Send message" /></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "lindsay@ascensionmarketingresults.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data

    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $tel            = filter_var($_POST["tel"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $date           = filter_var($_POST["date"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $text           = filter_var($_POST["text"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $number         = filter_var($_POST["number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<3){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = "Message: ".$message."\r\n\r\nName: ".$user_name."\r\nEmail: ".$user_email ;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $tel, $date, $text, $number, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .'. Thank you for your email.'));
        die($output);
            echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']."<br> requested with ".strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry the php didn't upload properly:

Comment: Is this giving you the `Could not send mail!` error? Does the HTML have a `<form>` element around it?

Comment: WizPip, it says:Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration. I didn't put form around due to the way it was structured... should I change it to say form? I was concerned it was the added form elements that I have which I didn't code properly in the php file

Comment: You should definitely have your form wrapped in a form element. Regarding the error you're getting though, is this script on your local machine or on a server somewhere? It's likely that you need to set up the mail server part of the php.ini file, with your mail server details.